# Oracle Timestamp - find records older than 60 seconds

Tags: oracle, time

In an Oracle table, I have an updated_dt stored like this: 25-NOV-14 10.20.32.000000 PM

I would like to select from this table where the records are more than 60 seconds old. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
select systimestamp-60/(24*60*60) time from dual
```

to find the time from 60 seconds ago but if I put in my where clause:

```
where updated_dt < (select systimestamp-60/(24*60*60) time from dual)
```

then nothing ever comes up...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the data type of `updated_dt`?  Is it a `date`?  Or a `timestamp`?  A `timestamp with [local] time zone`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the column is a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP [WITH [LOCAL] TIMESTAMP]` column **and not a `VARCHAR2`** you can use this one:

`where updated_dt < systimestamp - INTERVAL '60' SECOND`

I always wonder why people use gain and again this stupid `SELECT ... from dual` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Use the below

```
where to_date(to_char(updated_dt,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') > to_date(to_char(systimestamp,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')- (60/(24*60*60))
```